# Perl- file path matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to cut the directory path in the Perl.
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filespec = "/var/www/grammer/lecture12.mp4";
my $relative = $1 if $filespec =~ m{/var/www(.*)};
print $relative;
```

The output is

```
/grammer/lecture12.mp4
```

Now if I don't have the `/var/www` in the path i.e. only

```
my $filespec = "/grammer/lecture12.mp4";
```

The output for this is blank with a warning. But I am expecting this output path `/grammer/lecture12.mp4`.

May be I am matching the path `/var/www/`. That's why it is not giving desired output. Or is there something else wrong? And I would like to do in `regex` only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, `$relative` is set *if* `$filespec` matches the pattern. Not sure what other behaviour you expect from that. Also, not sure why you're so set on using regex, when there are [better ways](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the substitution operator `s///` like this. I don't know what you intend to use your modified path for, but you should note that a leading slash implies that it is an absolute path, located at the root of the file system

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14.1;

my $filespec = '/var/www/grammar/lecture12.mp4';
my $relative = $filespec =~ s|^/var/www||r;

say $relative;
```

#### output

```
/grammar/lecture12.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You get warning because $relative is only initialized if you have /var/www in $filespec, the same reason for it to be empty.

Also you should check that $file_spec begins with /var/www, but not contains it inside.

Also you omitted slash after www, so your regex will fail on paths like /var/www2/and/so/on.mp4

Considering this you should change the line

```
my $relative = $1 if $filespec =~ m{/var/www(.*)};
```

to the following code:

```
$filespec =~ m{^/var/www/(.*)};
my $relative = $1||$filespec;
```